# Unable to ping a specific system on IPv6

Tags: networking, ipv6

I've enabled IPv6 on my network, using DHCPv6 and subnet fd00::/64.
My DHCP server's IP is fd00::1:1:1 and I'm unable to ping it from some systems on my network.

My radvd.conf:

```
interface br0
{
    AdvSendAdvert on;
    AdvManagedFlag on;
    AdvOtherConfigFlag on;

    MinRtrAdvInterval 3;
    MaxRtrAdvInterval 60;

    prefix fd00::/64
    {
        AdvAutonomous off;
        AdvOnLink on;
    };
};
```

IPv6 addresses on DHCP server:

```
# ip -6 addr list dev br0
4: br0:  mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 fd00::1:1:1/64 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::223:5aff:fe5c:3035/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

On client:

```
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : fd00::5(Preferred)
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 27 July 2016 19:37:38
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 02 August 2016 22:13:23
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : fdf4:9ff3:68e4:3600:8c44:7b7d:8cd5:22b5(Preferred)
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : fdf4:9ff3:68e4:3600:e10d:6a8d:d16f:ebf0(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::8c44:7b7d:8cd5:22b5%9(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.5(Preferred)
```

Server is running Ubuntu 16.04.1, client is Windows 10.

I'm able to ping from server to client:

```
$ ping6 -w5 -c1 fd00::5
PING fd00::5(fd00::5) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fd00::5: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.245 ms

--- fd00::5 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.245/0.245/0.245/0.000 ms
```

But not client to server:

```
>ping -n 1 fd00::1:1:1

Pinging fd00::1:1:1 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for fd00::1:1:1:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 0, Lost = 1 (100% loss),
```

I can ping the link-local address though.

Client can ping other IPv6 systems on my network:

```
>ping -n 1 fd00::1
```

Pinging fd00::1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from fd00::1: time<1ms

Ping statistics for fd00::1:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

It's not being blocked by iptables on server (raw, mangle and nat tables are also empty with policy set to ACCEPT):

```
# ip6tables -n -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I've spent a few days trying to figure this out, but not got anywhere. Has anyone got any ideas?

Routing table from Windows:

```
>route print -6
===========================================================================
Interface List
  9...54 04 a6 25 ea 42 ......Intel(R) 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
  4...54 04 a6 25 f2 de ......Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
  7...00 50 56 c0 00 01 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
 10...00 50 56 c0 00 08 ......VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
  2...00 ff 27 7c db d5 ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
  8...5c f3 70 69 f8 ad ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
  3...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  9    266 ::/0                     fe80::223:5aff:fe5c:3035
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
  9    266 fd00::/64                On-link
  9    266 fd00::5/128              On-link
  9     26 fdf4:9ff3:68e4:3600::/64 On-link
  9    266 fdf4:9ff3:68e4:3600:8c44:7b7d:8cd5:22b5/128
                                    On-link
  9    266 fdf4:9ff3:68e4:3600:a44b:f98d:2032:cb57/128
                                    On-link
  7    276 fe80::/64                On-link
 10    276 fe80::/64                On-link
  9    266 fe80::/64                On-link
  3    306 fe80::/64                On-link
  3    306 fe80::8d:10d8:a79e:ff1d/128
                                    On-link
  7    276 fe80::68f0:76f0:9474:d11d/128
                                    On-link
  9    266 fe80::8c44:7b7d:8cd5:22b5/128
                                    On-link
 10    276 fe80::9875:1c54:698b:b9d2/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
  7    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
 10    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
  9    266 ff00::/8                 On-link
  3    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Comment: Have you tried checking with `tcpdump` or Wireshark whether the ping packets are sent & received? Also, next time use `ip6tables-save`.

Comment: Also, you said the subnet is `fd00::/64`, but the client appears to have two _more_ addresses – in the `fdf4:9ff3:68e4:3600::/64` subnet. Are those intentional?

Comment: The fdf4 addresses are being auto assigned (don't know what by). tcpdump on server doesn't show it being received, Wireshark on client doesn't show it being sent.. only a neighbour discovery request.

Comment: Then you need to look at the client's routing table.

Comment: Is the ndisc request for the IP you're trying to ping?

Comment: Yes, the ND request is for the IP I'm trying to ping, as well as a reply. Routing table looks fine to me (added to question). And as already said, I can ping other systems in the same subnet, just not that one.

Comment: The Unique Local Addresses are probably coming from your home router. There's probably little reason not to use them.